# Android: How to give application memory location for installing app

Tags: android

I want to install an application in a specific location inside of application memory not in system memory. What should i do?

This code installs the selected application in phone memory I want to

```
            @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    FileInformation information = files_list.get(position);
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(information.getPath())), 
             "application/" +
                        "vnd.android.package-archive");
        this.startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Comment: you want to install in sd card.??

Answer (score 0):

path of sdCard is:

```
String sdCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() 
        + "/yourFolder"
        + "/yourFile.apk";
```

also, for install app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(apkPath)),
                  "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```